# Fastest way to search through iterable chain combinations?

Tags: python, search, iterator, set, combinations

What is the fastest way I can find the sum of a power set with 10k and over integers?

```
long_list = [randrange(0,10000) for r in xrange(10000)]

desired_sum = sum(randint(0,10000)+randint(0,10000)+randint(0,10000))

def powerset(iterable):
    # notice the '3' in combinations(s,3), taking all combinations of 3. 
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, 3) for r in range(len(s)+1))

ps = powerset(set(long_list))

if desired_sum > 29994:
    print "cannot compute"
else:
    for i in ps:
        if sum(i) == desired_sum: # last combination of chain 9999+9998+9997
            print i
```

It takes too long for my pc to compute, and I wanted to ask for some tips on how to process large combinations like this.

In order to search like this, my for loop has to exhaust the entire list before fining the sum of the combinations.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? If your goal is iterate over *all* the combinations, well.. that's a lot. If you only need some of them, you can come up with some pre-processing for trimming the initial ranges.

Comment: @shx2 the output I would is to print the combination that is equal to my sum, 29994, but this number will change. What can you suggest to perform pre-process trimming for an variable sum value?

Comment: but you already know that answer. here's the most efficient solution: `print (9999,9998,9997)`

Comment: @shx2 Yes but it's meant to be a variable, with these numbers that add up to my sum, I will use them to generate other things

Comment: @czl You do realize that your program has to compare `166616670000` combinations, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes at max 1.6 x 10^11 operations, is there any techniques to pre-process the `desired_sum`?

Comment: should that be `combinations(r, 3)`?

Comment: @gnibbler That `for` loop itself is not necessary.

Comment: @gnibbler combinations(r,3) takes only the power sets with elements of 3

Comment: @gnibbler I believe the whole solution can be written like this `return [item for item in combinations(s, 3) if sum(item) == 29994]`

Comment: @thefourtheye the completion time will still be very bad anyway i try to do this?

Comment: As a side note, why are you building a list just to call `set` on it (why not just use a set comprehension?) just to pass it to a function that immediately calls `list` on its argument?

Comment: Also, in what sense is chaining together `len(s)` copies of `combinations(s, 3)` meant to be a `powerset(s)`, or anything useful at all?

Comment: @abarnert Itertools cook book came with the `len` http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

Comment: @czl Check this program http://ideone.com/nrPzvr. This is as per gnibbler's suggestion. This can produce the results in reasonable time.

Comment: @czl: The recipe is _using_ the `r`, because it's actually generating the powerset—that is, `combinations(s, r)` for every `r`. You're just generating `combinations(s, 3)` over and over again.

Comment: Meanwhile, your question is asking for the fastest way to sum up all of the elements of your giant iterable; there really is no faster way to do that than to iterate over it. (OK, your could parallelize or vectorizing chunks for maybe an 8x improvement, but beyond that…) But what makes you think that's a useful way to do anything? What are you actually trying to do? If it's just to _find_ the sum, you don't need the set in the first place.

Comment: @czl Please check my answer. Thats the fastest possible I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20062162/1903116

Comment: @abarnert Please check my solution. I think thats the fastest possible. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20062162/1903116

Comment: @czl Do you want all the permutations of `9997, 9998, 9999` in the output? Or just `9999, 9998, 9997` is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the desired sum, you just need to iterate over all the *pairs* (`combinations(s, 2)`), and test if the missing element is in the set

Example thanks to @thefourtheye

```
from random import randrange
from itertools import combinations
long_list = [randrange(0,10000) for r in xrange(10000)]

def powerset(it):
    return [(i[0], i[1], 29994 - sum(i)) for i in combinations(it, 2) if 29994 - sum(i) in it]

def main():
    print powerset(set(long_list))

import cProfile
cProfile.run("main()")
```

Comment: what do you mean by pairs?

Comment: @czl Look at this program. This is as per his suggestion. This will produce the result in reasonable time. http://ideone.com/nrPzvr

Comment: @thefourtheye, hope you don't mind if I add that to my answer

Comment: @gnibbler Found the fastest possible solution, please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20062162/1903116

Answer (score 3):

Found the fastest solution.

```
from random import randrange
long_list = [randrange(0,10000) for r in xrange(10000)]

def main():
    myList, result = sorted(set(long_list), reverse = True), []
    myLen = len(myList)
    for i in xrange(myLen):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, myLen):
            if 29994 - (myList[i] + myList[j]) > myList[j]: break
            for k in xrange(j + 1, myLen):
                tsum = myList[i] + myList[j] + myList[k]
                if tsum < 29994:
                    break
                elif tsum == 29994:
                    result.append((myList[i], myList[j], myList[k]))
    print result
    return result

import cProfile
cProfile.run("main()")
```

This runs within a second on my machine. The beauty of this solution is that, this can be generalized with recursion for any number of items which match the sum.

Comment: Running this against gnibbler's solution repeatedly, it doesn't seem to do the right thing. When there is exactly one answer, it returns no answers. Only when there are exactly four answers does it return one of them. I'm not sure whether yours or gnibbler's implements what the OP actually wanted, but they definitely don't implement the same thing, and gnibbler's is the one that implements the same thing the OP's code does.

Comment: The first problem is that you're (in essence) iterating over the set of sorted combinations, while the OP and gnibbler are iterating over all combinations, so they'll pick up all three permutations of (9997, 9998, 9999) as valid answers.

Comment: The second problem is that, by chaining together three copies of the combinations of the set, the OP's code allows answers like (9996, 9999, 9999). Whether that's an error, or it should only do so if there were multiple 9999's in `long_list` (a fact that he's thrown away by converting to a set and back to a list), or it's what he wants, I can't say. But again, gnibbler's preserves that behavior, while yours only searches combinations of the set.

Comment: @abarnert The input is generated randomly. So, we cannot run both the programs for the same input. And OP also uses only unique numbers, `ps = powerset(set(long_list))`. So, `9996, 9999, 9999` is not an option. But, this will not pick up all permutations of `9997, 9998, 9999`, as you rightly pointed out. Need to check with OP.

Comment: Copying and paste the two functions into one script, and then running them both on one list, is trivial. And that's exactly what I did. Your code always misses `9996, 9999, 9999`, while gnibbler's prints it (and the OP's would as well, but I didn't wait that long; I verified they were equivalent with a much smaller list).

Comment: And I just explained why `9996, 9999, 9999` is an option. If you make a set of the list, then chain together three copies of that set, you have `9999` in there three times. (It's slightly more complicated to explain in gnibbler's case, but just run his program three or four times and you'll see that output, which should prove that it's possible output…)

Comment: @abarnert Then, that program is wrong, I believe. As per OP's question, he is using a set over long_list and picks combinations of 3 from the unique list. So, `9996, 9999, 9999` will not be an option, right?

Comment: The OP's code very clearly chains together N copies. What possible reason could he have for doing this? The idea that it's an attempt to make `9996, 9999, 9999` a valid option is just a guess—but since he never answered when repeatedly asked why he was doing that, guesses are all we have. I think the fact that he accepted gnibbler's answer, which prints out `9996, 9999, 9999` every few runs, is pretty good evidence that he was trying to get that answer. If you think he _shouldn't_ want that, you may be right, and if you explain why, that would make your answer even better.

Comment: @abarnert You know that None of us can explain why he shouldn't want that :) But, the fix is simple, in the second and third loops, we can just leave the beginning of the ranges as `j` and `k` respectively.

Comment: @abarnert With that change, I could see this program generating `[(9999, 9999, 9996), (9998, 9998, 9998), (9999, 9998, 9997)]`

Comment: Good point; gnibbler's answer only generates one permutation of `(9999, 9999, 9996)`, and doesn't generate `(9998, 9998, 9998)`, because it effectively treats one of the values differently from the other two. So, if the OP wants that output, he probably _shouldn't_; he either wants all duplicates, or none, not just duplicates between the two special positions but not the other three.

Comment: Which means I've gone back to my original guess that the OP did the duplication for no reason at all (or, rather, because he was copying and pasting and shotgun-debugging code he didn't understand), not because he was trying to achieve something in particular… In which case this is categorically a better answer than gnibbler's. (Too bad I already up-voted you, so I can't do it again.) Still, his is a good answer for what the OP asked ("how do I improve this silly code", rather than "how do I do what I really want").

Comment: @abarnert lol. He really wasn't sure about his requirements, I believe and he hasn't clarified it well even after asking so many times. And the code in gnibbler's answer was written by me, but the idea was gnibbler's.

Answer (score 1):

This genexpr:

```
(combinations(s, 3) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

… just generates the same combinations over and over, len(s) times. That's not a powerset. More importantly, it's just wasted effort; if none of the combinations match, none of the combinations in the various copies of those combinations will match either.

So, you can optimize by just not adding this extra work:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    return combinations(iterable, 3)
```

Since your iterable is expected to be about 6300 members long (that's about how many unique values you should expect in your list of 10000, so calling `set` and then `list` will give you a list about that long), this will make things roughly 6300x faster.